# GridView OnItemClickListener is not calling onItemClick

Tags: java, android, gridview, listadapter

I am trying to set up an **OnItemClickListener** for the items in my Gridview.  For some reason the onItemCLick method within the listener is never called.

Setting the listener and the adapter:

```
UsersAdapter usersAdapter = new UsersAdapter(venueUsers);
gridView.setAdapter(usersAdapter);
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Users.this, com.roqbot.client.login.Profile.class);
        intent.putExtra("idUser", id);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

My Adapter:

```
private class UsersAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ListAdapter {
    private JSONArray users;

    private UsersAdapter(JSONArray users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return users.length();
    }

    public JSONObject getItem(int position) {
        return users.optJSONObject(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return users.optJSONObject(position).optInt("idUser");
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = Users.this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.user_icon, null);

        JSONObject user = getItem(position);

        TextView username = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.username);
        username.setText(user.optString("sName"));

        TextView userScore = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userScore);
        int iDJScore = user.optInt("iDJScore");
        if (iDJScore > 0) {
            userScore.setText(Integer.toString(iDJScore));
        }
        else {
            userScore.setVisibility(TextView.INVISIBLE);
            ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userScoreBg)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        TextView userLevel = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userLevel);
        userLevel.setText(user.optString("iDJLevel"));

        TextView userMatch = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userMatch);
        ImageView matchIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.matchIcon);
        int iCompatibility = user.optInt("iCompatibility");
        if (iCompatibility != 0) {
            userMatch.setText( iCompatibility + "%");
        }
        else {
            userMatch.setVisibility(TextView.INVISIBLE);
            matchIcon.setVisibility(ImageView.INVISIBLE);
        }

        ImageView userIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.userIcon);
        String sUserIcon = user.optString("sImageUrl-thumb");
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(sUserIcon, Users.this, userIcon);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

I am pretty baffled as to why the click listener isn't working.  This code works in a lot of other places for me.

Comment: I think you missed one closing braces for your gridView's onClickListener..

Comment: checked if ur imports r proper??

Comment: If the brackets or parenthesis were wrong it wouldn't compile right?  Just checked the imports and everything looks correct.

Comment: I actually found a workaround.  I just set a click listener on the ImageView in the convertView method of the adapter.  This works but seems sloppier.

Answer (score 6):

I had same problem.

In my situation, "android:focusable = true" block item click event

In My GridList Item Layout

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/auction_item_title"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:singleLine="true"
    ***android:focusable="true"***
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
/>
```

I remove [ android:focusable="true" ], problem is solved

Comment: to save the problem , you should add the `android:focusable="false"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"`

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you just need to make sure that the items in the grid aren't clickable. GridViews can't handle clickable items. Buttons for example won't work. And also if you made an item from a LinearLayout, or any other non-clickable item, you have to make sure that you didn't set the property: clickable="true".